# Getting user data with req.body inside a useEffect that then displaying inside a table

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I got a problem when I try the normal fetch method inside my react app not returning anything and think something to do with my req.body. I have tried using axios.get but giving me varouis errors.

See below my code:
useEffect with fetch: (Don't return anything)

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
      const manager = {
          "manager":managerName
      }
      fetch(`http://localhost:5000/staff/getStaffM`,manager)
      .then(resp=>resp.json())
      .then(data=>setData(data))

},[]);
```

useEffect with axios.get: (returning the following error = Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: resp.json is not a function. (In 'resp.json()', 'resp.json' is undefined) )

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
      const manager = {
          "manager":managerName
      }
      axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/staff/getStaffM`,manager)
      .then(resp=>resp.json())
      .then(data=>setData(data))

  },[]);
```

Backend Routing:

```
 const getStaffM = asyncHandler(async(req,resp)=>{
        const staff = await Staff.find({employeeManager: req.body.manager})
        if(staff){
            resp.status(200).json(staff)
        }
    else{
        resp.status(400)
        throw new Error ("Could not find this manager")
 }
```

This is working when I try it in post man but not in React app.

See below successful postman screenshot:

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HVye.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you instead of resp.json()  use resp.data?

Comment: GET request with the payload? I don't think that's a good standard to implement and not sure either `fetch` or `axios` support GET call with request payload.

Comment: Grelnog I added resp.data but still returing empty object:

   axios.get('http://localhost:5000/staff/getStaffM',manager)
      .then(resp=>setData(resp.data))

Comment: Mchowdam what wll the best approach be since I only want to show the data on the table where a manager can see all the staff that he manage

Comment: @GlenBowler Check [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro). They are not accepting the request body for GET calls. I would suggest you change that body as request parameters.

Comment: mchowdam Thanks alot for that tip so glad you gave me the link and also advised that was not possible with GET. Did not know can use post for request. Learn something new everyday. See below my solution if some one ever got same issue:

 React.useEffect(()=>{
    const manager ={
        "manager": managerName
    }
    axios.post("http://localhost:5000/staff/getStaffM", manager)
        .then(resp=>setData(resp.data))

  },[]);